# Gupshup always visible Custom Keyboard

Tags: gupshup

Is it possible always show Custom Keyboard (option Vanilla,Chocolate,Butterscotch) in gupshup?

Original example:

```
if (event.message == "hi"){
        var payload = {"type":"survey","question":"Hello,What is your
                favourite flavour of icecream?","options":
                      ["Vanilla","Chocolate","Butterscotch"]};
        context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(payload));
        return;        
   }

if (event.message == "Vanilla"){
        context.sendResponse("Ok, getting vanilla ice cream");
        return;
   }
```

Comment: I believe you are referring to alway show custom keyboard on Telegram? If yes, it is not possible to set this as the user's default way of answering to the chatbot. But as a workaround, you can always send bot messages as a structured(survey template as demonstrated in your sample code) message.